# Redefining \em to do nothing in references part of document

Tags: bibtex, japanese, platex

My current format is the following:

[image: Current Format]

I want it to be like this:

[image: Result Format]

I identified the problem is `> bibtex References.bib` produces `main.bbl`
with the following result.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{shimomura}
下村健治.
\newblock {\em うんこうんこうんち}.
\newblock コロナ社, 1998.

\end{thebibliography}
```

I need the {em} part to not turn bold. Following, a suggestion in the comment, I carefully follow [this article](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex) to make compilable file.
This is the contents of `main.tex`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4j]{jreport}
\usepackage[dvipdfm]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\LaTeX{} \cite{latex2e} is a set of macros built atop \TeX{} \cite{texbook}.
\clearpage
\baselineskip=7.0mm
\bibliographystyle{plain} % We choose the "plain" reference style
\bibliography{refs} % Entries are in the refs.bib file

\end{document}
```

This is the example `refs.bib` included in the said article.

```
@book{texbook,
  author = {Donald E. Knuth},
  year = {1986},
  title = {The {\TeX} Book},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley Professional}
}

@book{latex:companion,
  author = {Frank Mittelbach and Michel Gossens
            and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle
            and Chris Rowley},
  year = {2004},
  title = {The {\LaTeX} Companionお願いします。},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley Professional},
  edition = {2}
}

@book{latex2e,
  author = {Leslie Lamport},
  year = {1994},
  title = {{\LaTeX}: a Document Preparation Systemお願いします。},
  publisher = {Addison Wesley},
  address = {Massachusetts},
  edition = {2}
}

@article{knuth:1984,
  title={Literate Programming},
  author={Donald E. Knuth},
  journal={The Computer Journal},
  volume={27},
  number={2},
  pages={97--111},
  year={1984},
  publisher={Oxford University Press}
}

@inproceedings{lesk:1977,
  title={Computer Typesetting of Technical Journals on {UNIX}},
  author={Michael Lesk and Brian Kernighan},
  booktitle={Proceedings of American Federation of
             Information Processing Societies: 1977
             National Computer Conference},
  pages={879--888},
  year={1977},
  address={Dallas, Texas}
}
```

Compiled with

```
> platex main 
> bibtex main
> platex main
> platex main
> dvipdfm main
```

I have omitted plenty of lines from the original main tex file, such that the title of the references changes but the problem still presist, the japanese part of the title is bolded.
[image: bolded even when many lines removed]

Comment: Instead of not producing `\em`, how about temporarily redefining `\em` to do nothing?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Sure, should I make a new question? Or you could make one yourself and self answer?

Comment: I would make a suggestion if your question would contain a compilable test file including an example entry for the bibliography...

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz So I should make a new question about redefining \em to do nothing, that contain a compilable test file that produce the problem i have?

Comment: No, you should edit this question.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz i have included compilable tex file

Comment: Why not just add `\let\em\relax` before the `\bibliography` command?

Comment: @AlanMunn and suppose that there is other section after references, and that section needs em to be bolded again what command should i use?

Comment: Then enclose the whole thing in a group `{\let\em\relax\bibliography{..}}`